# Akka: Forwarded Messages are being lost

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Hi I have a intuitive case of message forwarding as you can see below. Actor1 is forwarding multiple messages to Actor2, however Actor2 only receives portions of messages, for some reason some messages get lost without a trace. For example, Actor1 forwards 10 messages to Actor2, however Actor2 receives only 7 of them. I see no exception or ambiguous messages in the logs. Why could this be happening?

```
Actor1 extends Actor {
   val actor2 = context.actorOf(Actor2.props)
   def receive = {
      case msg: SomeMessage => {
         log.info("Forwarding SomeMessage to Actor2")
         actor2 forward msg
      }
   }
}

Actor2 extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case msg: SomeMessage => {
          //Do something
          log.info("SomeMessage received from Actor1")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you using the default mailbox?

Comment: do you lose only forwarded messages or also direct messages to `actor2`?

Comment: Can you specify Akka version? Enable debug logging and see whether you get some dead letters.

Comment: If your "do something" is very long, it may be that Actor2 is lagging behind, having its mailbox growing because of the messages sent from Actor1 and not yet processed.

Comment: also, is there any pattern in which messages do you lose? add a unique id for your `SomeMessage` class, like `case class SomeMessage(id: Int, ...)` and log the `id` too

Comment: I would also use `LoggingReceive` to log which messages are being processed.